# How to Access .mdb Data Source in PHP Linux?

Tags: php, linux, odbc, unixodbc

I just installed *unixODBC* in order to access my .mdb data source on *PHP.5.3 CentOS 6.10* using this commands:

```
# yum install unixODBC
```

In Windows i could simply uncomment `extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll` on *php.ini* and restart *Httpd / Apache* in order to access my *.mdb*, and then made connection thorugh *PDO* like this :

```
<?php

    $dsn = "{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}";
    $db = "/home/www/html/cetak_absensi/uploaded/db_access/myDB.mdb";
    $user = "";
    $pass = "";

    $connection = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER=".$dsn.";charset=UTF-8; Dbq=".$db."; Uid=".$user."; Pwd=".$pass.";");
    ...
    ...
?>
```

After installed *unixODBC* and *PDO-ODBC* already running on my php, i run my code above, unfortunately i face this error :

```
[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified php linux
```

After searched on another post here, i think my DSN is not correct.

What is the correct DSN for this in Linux ?

Is that really possible to access my *.mdb* data source through  *PHP-PDO* in *Linux* especially *CentOS 6.10*?

**UPDATE**

After searched i have found an article explained about this. 
And i installed *libmdodbc1* from this resource [libmdbodbc](https://centos.pkgs.org/6/forensics-x86_64/libmdbodbc1-0.7-43.13.el6.x86_64.rpm.html) and add following line in */etc/odbcinst.ini* :

```
# Source Came From:
# 1. https://centos.pkgs.org/6/forensics-x86_64/libmdbodbc1-0.7-43.13.el6.x86_64.rpm.html
# 2. https://gist.github.com/amirkdv/9672857
# etc.
[MDBTools]
Description = MDBTools Driver
Driver64      = /usr/lib64/libmdbodbc.so.1.0.0
Setup64       = /usr/lib64/libmdbodbc.so.1.0.0
FileUsage   = 1
UsageCount  = 1
```

And then i change the connection like this:

*connection.php*

```
<?php
    /*
    ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '100M');
    ini_set('post_max_size', '100M');
    echo ini_get('upload_max_filesize'), ", " , ini_get('post_max_size');
    echo php_uname();
    */
    set_time_limit(600);

    $query = 'SELECT * FROM LEAVECLASS1';
    $mdb_file = '/var/www/html/cetak_absensi/uploaded/db_access/db_absensi_backup.mdb';
    $uname = explode(" ",php_uname());
    print_r($uname);
    $os = $uname[0];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $os;
    switch ($os){
      case 'Windows':
        $driver = '{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}';
        break;
      case 'Linux':
        $driver = 'MDBTools';
        break;
      default:
        exit("Don't know about this OS");
    }
    $dataSourceName = "odbc:Driver=$driver;DBQ=$mdb_file;";
    echo "<br>";

    try {
        $connection = new \PDO($dataSourceName);
        $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $result = $connection->prepare($query);
        $result->execute();
        $data = $result->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "<br><br>";
        echo "There is an error " . $e->getMessage();
        echo "<br><br>";
    }

    // I think this following code cause this error:
    //$result = $connection->query($query)->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    echo "<br>";
    print_r($data);
    echo "<br>";
    var_dump($connection);
```

After run this code the browser said :

```
The connection was reset
```

I have increased my *memory_limit* and *max_execution_time* in *php.ini* but still throw the same message.

Can you tell me why the browser throw this message ?

Maybe i have set wrong configuration or my *.mdb* data is too large.

**UPDATE 2**

I uninstalled my `libmdodbc1` (my previous `libmdodbc` on first update above). And then installed libmdodbc1 using `$ sudo yum install libmdodbc1` and my configuration in */etc/odbcinst.ini* is still same like previous (same as on first update above) and then restarted the service. My reference is this article [How to handle MS Access MDB files in Linux with PHP5 PDO and ODBC](https://gist.github.com/amirkdv/9672857).

Furthermore i changed `$mdb_file` variable to `$mdb_file = '/var/www/html/cetak_absensi/uploaded/db_access/db_new.mdb'` that only has a table with 3 records in it. And also i added `var_dump($data);` to see the fetched data.

db_new.mdb looks like this:

```
ID  Nama Depan     Nama Belakang      Pekerjaan
1   First Name 1    Last Name 1       Programmer
2   First Name 2    Last Name 2       Guru
3   First Name 3                      Dokter
```

After i ran *connection.php*, `var_dump($connection);` and `var_dump($data)` respectively result :

```
// var_dump($connection);
object(PDO)#1 (0) { }

// var_dump($data);
array(2) { [0]=> array(4) { ["ID"]=> string(1) "2" ["Nama Depan"]=> NULL ["Nama Belakang"]=> NULL ["Pekerjaan"]=> NULL } [1]=> array(4) { ["ID"]=> string(1) "3" ["Nama Depan"]=> NULL ["Nama Belakang"]=> NULL ["Pekerjaan"]=> NULL } }
```

(END OF FIRST TRIAL).

Why `$data` only has *fieldnames* with *NULLs* value ?

Thought the connection already made it, i tested with my previous *.mdb* file (db_absensi_backup.mdb) and the page still showing the same issue.

```
The connection was reset
```

And the *error_log* said:

```
[Tue Jun 02 14:47:12 2020] [notice] child pid 5366 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

(END OF SECOND TRIAL).

The first trial on this second update is almost made it, while the second trial with my real *.mdb* file seems like the package is out of date.

Can you tell me why these happened ?

And are these because i made wrong configuration before ?

Comment: I have searched for about 3 weeks and have not solved this yet. Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: It would be interesting to know where exactly the connection was reset. By the server in http context? By the database file? What is the relevant output from `phpinfo()`?

Comment: @DanielW. : i don't know exactly what you want to know in the `phpinfo()` page. But in `phpinfo()` surely my `odbc`, `pdo` and `pdo_odbc` are already enabled.
And my _.mdb_ file is about 172MB.

Comment: @DanielW. By the way `var_dump($connection)` results `object(PDO)#1 (0) { }` in code above, while after i added `$result = $connection->prepare($query);
        $result->execute();
        $data = $result->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` line then the `The connection was reset`occur in browser. Is that because my file is too large ?

Comment: You could easily test that by using a blank MDB but I don't think it is too large. You should investigate why the connection is getting reset. What error is written to your PHP logfile?

Comment: @DanielW.: I have tested with very small .mdb data source which only contain a table and you are right still not working. And my error_log give a notice : `[notice] child pid 5849 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)`, this is the last notice after i ran my code.

Comment: Ok, segmentation fault is the worst of all errors, because it is very hard to debug and originating from C code, not from PHP. Make sure there is no compatibility issue between your installed extensions and drivers.

Comment: `yum install unixODBC` might give you a version of unixODBC that is rather old. use `odbcinst -j` to check the version and consider upgrading if it is older than 2.3.7 (and *especially* if it is older than 2.3.5).

Comment: @DanielW. My unixODBC version is 2.2.14 (too old). i will try to upgrade it and see the result after that

Comment: @DanielW. I have searched about latest unixODBC version for CentOS 6.10, i think the latest version is 2.2.14, source here [link](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=unixODBC)

Comment: @DanielW. : By the way beside installed unixODBC using above command, i also installed `libmdbodbc1` (MDBTools) through this source [link](https://centos.pkgs.org/6/epel-x86_64/mdbtools-libs-0.6-0.7.cvs20051109.el6.1.x86_64.rpm.html), do you think those packages' versions are too old ?

Comment: Im out of knowledge at this level but @GordThompson gave you somehint about min version. Maybe upgrading CentOS is also an option.

Comment: @DontBullyingMe - unixODBC 2.2.14 is over 11 years old and there have been many bugs fixed since then. If you can't get a newer RPM then you really should try to [install it from source](http://www.unixodbc.org/download.html).

Comment: @DanielW. : I am not being given privilege such as upgrading our CentOS version by my Boss. And i think he would insist about still using our current CentOS version.

Comment: @GordThompson Would unixODBC 2.3.7 suit for CentOS 6.10 version ? Based on this [link](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=unixODBC) i think it requires CentOS 8, dosen't it ?

Comment: @GordThompson : Well, i will try to install unixODBC 2.3.7 in my CentOS 6.10. Hopefully it will work.

Comment: By the way should in just install the new one or uninstall the old one and then install new one ?

Comment: @GordThompson I have installed _unixODBC 2.3.7_, from the given source but also i have to install `php-odbc` in order to activate my `ODBC` and `PDO_ODBC`. After ran  the packages i run `odbcinst -j` command, the command results `unixODBC 2.2.14
DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
...` as we can see the _unixODBC 2.2.14_ package version is still running instead of _unixODBC 2.3.7_. This because_unixODBC 2.2.14_  automatically is installed  with _pdo-odbc_  by default.

Comment: How can i synchronize `php-odbc` with _unixODBC 2.3.7_ instead of  2.2.14 version?

Comment: @GordThompson : I have updated the content of the question with more hint. Can you help me sir ?

Comment: @Daniel W. : I have updated the content of the question, Is the problem my package ?